# Issue regarding to build Docker image as Repository is not signed errors

Tags: docker, unix, pytorch, public-key

I am creating a docker image and everytime i got the following error. I don't have an access to sudo as I am not admin although its' related to the publick key is not assigned and the admin of system told me it's not key iussue it's repository issue. I don't have an idea about it can somebody guide me how i can resolve it as I am not able to access sudo

> Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.144kB Step 1/8 : FROM
> **mirasysindia/pytorch1.7-cuda11.0-py3.8-opencv4.2:latest**  --->
> e4a80aa9a385 Step 2/8 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install  --->
> Running in e3db7886a0d3 Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal
> InRelease [265 kB] Get:2
> https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64
> InRelease [1581 B] Err:2
> https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64
> InRelease   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the
> public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A4B469963BF863CC Get:3
> http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
> Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114
> kB] Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
> [108 kB] Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64
> Packages [11.3 MB] Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [885 kB] Get:8
> http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64
> Packages [1401 kB] Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> focal-security/main amd64 Packages [2036 kB] Get:10
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [33.4
> kB] Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64
> Packages [177 kB] Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main
> amd64 Packages [1275 kB] Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1164 kB] Get:14
> http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64
> Packages [27.5 kB] Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1515 kB] Get:16
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64
> Packages [30.2 kB] Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [2487 kB] Get:18
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 Packages
> [54.2 kB] Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [27.1 kB] Reading package
> **> lists... W: GPG error:
> https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64
> InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the
> public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A4B469963BF863CC E: The
> repository
> 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64
> InRelease' is not signed.** The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&
> apt-get install' returned a non-zero code: 100

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can trust the repo and put this in your Dockerfile before calling `apt update`:

```
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
```